# What does 'mapped' memory region mean in gdb-peda?

Tags: gdb

I was reading a [write-up](https://amritabi0s.wordpress.com/2017/04/24/plaid-ctf-2017-bigpicture-write-up/) of a binary exploitation where I came across the following:

[image]

What does the `mapped` keyword listed under `Name` column mean? What sort of memory region does it refer to?

Comment: http://nairobi-embedded.org/040_elf_sec_seg_vma_mappings.html